# Refresh div without changing it's content

Tags: html

Helllo, In my webpage I'm using multiple select lists which comes from 4 different XML files. I have a function that updates one div, containing "$scripts = simplexml_load_file($link);" and a couple of other div's with php functions inside, which perform further transformation of XML to select list.

```
<div id = "updatelink"></div>
<div id = "first unique list"></div>
<div id = "second unique list"></div>
<div id = "third unique list"></div>
```

My problem is when I update the main div with the link, the other's don't take the new value of $scripts and basically do nothing.

My question is how to update a div without posting new contents. I wan't the php functions inside the performing div's to update and grab new value for the $scripts variable. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need "Ajax for this"

```
$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  '#thisdiv');
```

[FAQ Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)